# Evaluate the following limit: $\lim\limits_{ n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!\sqrt n}{2^{2n}\cdot (n!)^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

Evaluate
$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{(2n)!\sqrt n}{2^{2n}\cdot (n!)^{2}}$.

Please help with steps, Dont know how to break it down to cancel out terms.

Comment: This limit diverges to positive infinity

Comment: Do you know of Stirling's approximation?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Could you write the formula with MathJax, so there's no ambiguity?

Comment: the equation is correct now

Answer (score 4):

Hint: using the Stirling approximation:$$
n!=\left(\frac n e\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$$
one easily finds that the limit is$$
\frac1{\sqrt\pi}.$$